# ansible: insert content of wordpress unique keys and salt into variable

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-16.04, ansible-galaxy

in handlers/main.yml I've got:

```
- name: get API information for wp-config
       uri:
        url: "https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/"
        return_contents: yes
       register: api_info
```

The tasks I'm trying to run are:

```
- name: copy sample config file
  copy:
    src: /var/www/wordpress/wp-config-sample.php
    dest: /var/www/wordpress/wp-config.php
    remote_src: yes
  notify: get API information for wp-config

 - name: run API handler now
   meta: flush_handlers

 - name: insert unique key and salts in wp-config
   lineinfile:
     path: /var/www/wordpress/wp-config.php
     regex: "put your unique phrase here"
     insertafter: "put your unique phrase here"
     line: "{{ api_info }}"
```

Unfortunately the value of variable api_info is not the content itself but:

```
{'status': 200, 'cookies': {}, 'date': 'Thu, 25 Oct 2018 14:53:42 GMT', 'url': 'https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/', 'transfer_encoding': 'chunked', 'changed': False, 'server': 'nginx', 'failed': False, 'connection': 'close', 'content_type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8', 'msg': 'OK (unknown bytes)', 'redirected': False, 'x_frame_options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'cookies_string': ''}
```

How can I get the actual content of the site?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

there is a small typo, the parameter is `return_content` not `return_contents` and the the `uri` module will return the contents of the uri call under `api_info.content`

```
---

- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - name: get API information for wp-config
      uri:
        url: "https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/"
        return_content: True
        method: GET
      register: api_info

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ api_info.content }}"
```

Comment: This is the second time I've posted an ansible playbook on the forum and in the previous post, the same problem. A typo. Although this could be harder to trace, as "return_contents" could also have been a valid option. Thanks for pointing it out.